# Vue Native Script don't want to install

Tags: vue.js, npm, nativescript-vue

I want to use vue-native, and I just need to install vue-native-scripts via npm, but it doesn't want to do it.

`PS E:\Coding\VueNative\YAAdmin> npm i vue-native-scripts`

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! path E:\Coding\VueNative\YAAdmin\node_modules\vue-native-scripts\src\bin\vue-native-script.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'E:\Coding\VueNative\YAAdmin\node_modules\vue-native-scripts\src\bin\vue-native-script.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-10T11_41_00_816Z-debug.log
```

I've tried to install all dependencies manually, but it does not work.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to your question title. We can tell you accepted an answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson no problem, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Install yarn: `npm install yarn -g`
2. In your project directory run `yarn add native-vue-scripts`

Thats all

Comment: Try to add some more details for the chance that someone will face the same problem and arrive here

Comment: When I run it: error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/native-vue-scripts: Not found".

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

NativeScript-Vue application template for quick prototyping with vue-cli (2.x).

```
yarn global add @vue/cli @vue/cli-init
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project-name>
cd <project-name>
```